# how to include images to ember cli

Tags: ember.js

i am doing a project using ember js as frontend.need help adding image.

for eg: in the template I want to add an image like

```
<img src="/location/image.png"/>
```

Where should I store the image? Is there any standard practices that follow in ember to store images and fonts?

Answer (score 3):

Good question, 
In your ember project there will be directories like this

```
/app
/config
/dist
/node_modules
/public
/tests
/tmp
/vendor
```

create a folder `assets` inside `public`, then create `images` inside `assets`. you can save your images in the `images` folder 
you can access the images using `url('/assets/images/image.png')`

for more details use this [documentation](https://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#asset-compilation)